# Tagging words based on some pre-defined categories

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics

Consider we have 16 different categories, e.g., Computer, Science, Art, Business etc. We have some words under each category as synonyms, homonyms etc which describes the possible meaning of each topic and its range. Consequently there might be similar or even same words which falls in more than one categories. Our aim is to submit a query (with max length of 3, after stop word removal) to a system and ask the system to put this word into the category with highest similarity. So my question is, beside Cosine similarity, is there any good technique for doing this?

I know already about `WordNet` and its extended version, `extjwnl`, however, I wish to implement one which gives enough flexibility to me for small usages.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Describe this 'query', I don't know what you mean by max length. It sounds like you need to be able to use 'pass by reference' as well as 'pass by value'. It is difficult to do this Java because the language does not support pointers. If it is the logic that you are interested in, you will need each word to contain all of the categories it fits in. The categories will thus need to have some kind of reference in each word. If you want to use java, you will need some kind oop model, and if speed is an issue, this may be difficult. Need more info.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer max length means the max keywords the query consist of. Imagine we have "printer laserjet" as a query. we wish to assign it to a category with highest similarity. each category is filled with a bag of most related words. so my question is, how to do it?

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing is very specific and beyond basic coding logic. Ultimately though, if you coded each category as an object, then you use a function to search each category for the word pattern. If you have multiple word patterns, you have to run the function that many times. Count the number of matches in each category and return the one with the most hits.

Comment: What would make this faster and more efficient, will be predicting or mapping the categories, so that half way through search you can determine the likelihood of a high result. If you really wanna check out something interesting, take a look at neural networks. That type of model might be helpful.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer that is too simple idea. so I sent this question for some `statistical` modeling.

Comment: Alternatively, you could code everything in C, and use really small data-structures. That might make things faster.

Comment: Take a look a neural nets. There are libraries out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are few things that can be done over and above to improve performance like stemming, lemmatization so that similarity is properly calculated.
Now as per similarity is concerned , you can use LDA(latent dirichlet allocation) to consider each document as combination of multiple topics.

LDA represents documents as mixtures of topics that spit out words with certain probabilities. It assumes that documents are produced in the following fashion: when writing each document, you

Decide on the number of words N the document will have (say, according to a Poisson distribution).
Choose a topic mixture for the document (according to a Dirichlet distribution over a fixed set of K topics). For example, assuming that we have the two food and cute animal topics above, you might choose the document to consist of 1/3 food and 2/3 cute animals.
Generate each word w_i in the document by:
First picking a topic (according to the multinomial distribution that you sampled above; for example, you might pick the food topic with 1/3 probability and the cute animals topic with 2/3 probability).
Using the topic to generate the word itself (according to the topic’s multinomial distribution). For example, if we selected the food topic, we might generate the word “broccoli” with 30% probability, “bananas” with 15% probability, and so on.
Assuming this generative model for a collection of documents, LDA then tries to backtrack from the documents to find a set of topics that are likely to have generated the collection.

https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html

Although this is unsupervised training where topics(categories are latent), you can use extension of LDA called LLDA(Labeled LDA).

I would not recommend using wordnet and cosine similarity as they doesn't consider co-occurences of terms and therefore might not work good with all datasets.

Comment: LDA is too slow. Should recommend something less time-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Jaccard Similarity can also be used in your case.

Jaccard Similarity converts a sentence into a set and then finds the intersection between the documents on which we have to find the similarity.

For more information on Jaccard Similarity you could take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index